# public_share in v2 API?

Tags: box-api

Box v1 API has a public_share function to make a file or folder shareable to public.
(http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923943/ApiFunction_public_share)

Is there a similiar function in V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, but it is planned.  V2 API is still in Beta and we will be delivering changes to it weekly until we declare it out-of-beta (aka, GA).